# Qt persistent QNetworkCookieJar

Tags: qt, webkit

In my Qt app, I need to save cookies between different runs of the program.

I read that [QNetworkCookieJar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkcookiejar.html) doesn't, for some reason, support permanent cookie storage; the manual tells me that I should basically do this myself.

I realize that writing a simple class like that isn't very hard, but this seems like a reinvention of the wheel of the worst degree, as surely somebody must've needed this before.

So my question basically is why doesn't Qt add permanent storage support to the default implementation? And is there a QNetworkCookieJar class somewhere on the internet that has permanent cookie support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [browser](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.8/demos/browser) in Qt Demos implements persistent storage with other fancy options (preference dialog, white list, black list, timer to save the cookies, ...).